# When did Superman say this line?

Tags: dc, superman

I've seen this quote a lot of times on the internet, but when was the first time Superman said this?

Was this in a comic book or movie?

> The world doesn't need a savior. But every day I hear people crying for one.

Comment: I believe Superman said that in *Superman Returns* (2006).. He replied to Lois Lane's essay..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As has been noted in comments, this is from the record-breaking blockbuster film [Superman Returns](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0348150/quotes).

> **Superman:** *Listen; what do you hear?*
>
> **Lois Lane:** *Nothing.*
>
> **Superman:** *I hear everything. **You wrote that the world doesn't need a savior, but every day I hear people crying for one.***